# What are some idiomatic way of saying "changing your face into someone else's face"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, idiom-request

One way I can think of saying this is saying "sculpt your face into a Harvey" or more generally "sculpt your face into a X" where X is a name of a specific person, like a celebrity, but I am not sure that this is idiomatic. Is there a similar way of saying this, if not can you think of a way of saying it idiomatically?

For example:

> You should sculpt your face into a Harvey to become popular with the
>   girls.

Comment: "You should sculpt your face into a Harvey to become popular with the girls." - This won't work. Believe me. I know.

Comment: Perhaps undergo a plastic surgery?

Comment: You should **morph** into a Harvey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how it would be possible to change your face into someone else's face. But for the purposes of this question, let's say you could, maybe by painting your face, using makeup, getting plastic surgery, wearing a mask, being one of the [Faceless Men](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Faceless_Men) on Game of Thrones, or assuming their identity entirely. Depending on what you're specifically doing, you could say:

> You should paint your face to look like Harvey's
>
> You should do your makeup to look like Harvey's face
>
> You should do your face like Harvey's
>
> You should get work* done on your face to look like Harvey
>
> You should wear a mask of Harvey's face
>
> You should swap faces with Harvey
>
> You should wear Harvey's face
>
> You should morph into Harvey
>
> You should shapeshift into Harvey
>
> You should become Harvey

*where *work* is a common euphemism for "plastic surgery"

If your face is made out of some malleable material like clay or silicone, maybe like the type of makeup they use in the movies, your original thought is good. I don't know about "a Harvey"; I'd probably just say "Harvey" or "Harvey's (face)". *mold* and *model* are similar words to *sculpt* that you can also use.

I don't know of an idiomatic expression that sounds best, especially not in general for all of these possibilities. But maybe this could work:

> You should model your face after Harvey's

where "model after X" just means something like "copy X".